# Force downloading the pdf created using jspdf

Tags: javascript, html, jspdf

Currently I am using jspdf to create a dynamic pdf , I am able to save the PDF by choosing save too , is there any possible way to force download the PDF created directly not by clicking save or discard button that appears .

I need only to **force download** the pdf , without using any server side , just has to be done in client side

when i view it dynamically the url is as follows

```
data:application/pdf;base64,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
```

Any help will be appreciated

url i get only if i  use `doc.output('datauri');`

if i want to force  save, is there anyway i can do that without using  `doc.save(pdfname);`

i used

```
var hiddenElement = document.createElement('a');

        hiddenElement.href = '#' ;
        hiddenElement.target = '_blank';
        hiddenElement.download = doc.output('datauri');
        hiddenElement.click();
```

but the above code just does the same as doc.save(pdfname); ,and even the .pdf extension also is not shown

Thanks

Comment: do you have a url to the pdf you're using? (i don't need to know it, just if)

Comment: sorry but i dont have it

Comment: @dandavis: jsPDF generates (and allows for download of) PDF files on the *client-side*.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: i'm aware of it's general MO, but was wondering specifically if it used dataURLs that could be fed to the 'download' attrib of an <A> tag for unprompted named file downloading from javascript.

Comment: i am able to download, but i need to force download it

Comment: @Samantha: Check the docs?  Maybe there's a method?  Or maybe you can trigger the click event on the download button with JavaScript?

Comment: ok, a url; good. just set the download attrib on an anchor tag to the url, call link.click() and call it an early afternoon.

Comment: any further confirmation is the result of a browser preference regarding download handling and cannot be over-come by js.